# saving form to txt. text does not show, why?

Tags: php, html, forms, web

I have a form on my website. I wanted to save to input to txt but when I submit data, the .txt file get larger (bytes increase) but no text shows up,
Here is the code

```
    <div>
    <form action="controller.php">
            <input name="card" id="card" type="email">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" >Submit</button>
                   </form>
                   </div>
```

Here is the .php code

```
<?php                
    $card = $_POST['card'];
    $file = fopen ('file.txt', "a");
    fwrite($file, $card . "\n");
    fclose($file);
     die(header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]));
?>
```

I have a sub domain with the same code and it works perfectly fine.
why is it not working and how do I fix?

I tried to change the id and the type

Comment: What happens when you log the content of `$card`?

Comment: you are missing method in the tag form. according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/method) "Unless explicitly specified, the default method is 'get'." $_GET instead of $_POST

Answer (score 1):

You have a very simple issue here. Let's see why by trying to do this on your file:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

You will see that after posting your form, you have no POST data. Your form is, by default (on your server or PHP configuration) sending the data not using the POST method, but the GET one (your other server probably is setup the opposite way).

To fix this, you can either change your $card variable to:

```
$card = $_GET['card'];
```

Or rather, and that would be a better option to make it more clear and avoid problems if you migrate your website on another server/PHP version, you could simply specify the method on your  tag:

```
<form action="controller.php" method="post">
```

Please, don't forget to secure the data that will be written in this file, malicious users exist and if you keep your code that simple, it might be a serious security issue.